# Apex: Sorting a Map

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex

I have a Map of type Sobject as a key and Integer as a value. The Sobject has field of type Text, other field of type date and another field of type Number(16,2). When I put data into the map and then debug it, the map returns data in a sorted way. The map sorts it by the Number field present in the Key i.e the number data field of the object. Can I get the map sorted by the date field of the object which is its key? Below is the rough structure of my Map and the key object fields.

```
 Map<Effort_Allocation__c, Double> cellContent;
 Effort_Allocation__c.Allocated_Effort_Hours__c; //The Number field by which the map gets sorted
 Effort_Allocation__c.Assignment_Date__c; // The date field by which I want the map to get sorted
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to use an object as a key for a map.  You should, instead, use the object's ID as the key.  The reasons for this are discussed in detail [here](http://foobarforce.com/2013/09/10/sobject-secret-life-equality-sets-maps/).  Short version - the object's values may change which changes the object's hash value and wrecks your map.

Although maps cannot be sorted directly, lists can be sorted, so they can be used to access map elements in sorted order.  You'll need a wrapper class for your object that implements the "Comparable" interface.  There's an example of that [here](http://abhithetechknight.blogspot.com/2013/12/salesforce-comparable-interface-using.html).  Note that the example sorts by date.

The class is declared with "comparable"

```
global class AccountHistoryWrapper implements Comparable{
```

and has the following CompareTo method

```
global Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {

// Cast argument to AccountHistoryWrapper
AccountHistoryWrapper aHW = (AccountHistoryWrapper)compareTo;

// The return value of 0 indicates that both elements are equal.
Integer returnValue = 0;

if ( aHW.account.CreatedDate > aHW.account.CreatedDate) {
// Set return value to a positive value.
returnValue = 1;
} else if ( aHW.account.CreatedDate < aHW.account.CreatedDate) {
// Set return value to a negative value.
returnValue = -1;
}

return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: how about text sorting?

Comment: for test sorting, the "compareTo" method would need to be changed.